# How can I change the version of my model in Azure Machine Learning service?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

When registering a model into Azure Machine Learning, it keeps increments the version number. Can i set the version number to a specific number? Or even stop it from increments every time?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The version number is controlled by the system and automatically increments.

You can use [tags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py#add-tags-tags-) to have custom tracking, for example

```
model.add_tags({"user-version":"alpha-0.1"})
```

Comment: But can change the version itself? Or is there anyway to reset it to start all over again?

Comment: No, the version cannot be changed. If you register the model under different name, that will restart the version number from 1.